# javascript issue with unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

I am getting an unexpected token { in the following line:

```
var that = this, tag_array = "img,object,embed,audio,video,iframe".split(','), 
 video_array = ['EMBED', 'OBJECT', 'VIDEO'], 
 is_ooyala = false, platform = {{ platform }};
```

seems like every thing is in balance. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using flowplayer for videos?

Comment: @RobW what is the issue with that?

Comment: `{{ platform }};` is causing the error. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I believe he is using the Django Template Language and  platform is a variable sent from a Python View. To use it in JavaScript you need double quotes: "{{ platform }}"

Comment: For future reference try to describe all languages and libraries you're using in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless this is dJango (in which cas you need to surround the `{{platform}}` in quotes`(platform = "{{ platform}}";)`, you're setting a variable equal to iteslf inside a double object litteral...
As everyone is saying this:

```
platform = {{ platform }};
```

is your issue. for testing switch to:

```
platform = "";
```

or try:

```
platform = {0: platform}
```

And you can revrive the value like this:

```
var x = platform.0;
```

or

```
var x = platform[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`{{ platform }}` is not valid, I am not sure what you are trying to do there to tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This part is causing an error:

```
platform = {{ platform }}
```

There are two issues there.  First, an object would contain `key: value` pairs, not just a single value and second, you can't use a variable itself in the declaration of that same variable.

I'm unsure what you're trying to accomplish so don't know what solution to recommend.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the line is what looks to be a nested object, but since it has no property name it is a syntax error:

```
platform = {{ platform }}
```

This was maybe intended to be something like

```
platform = { someProperty: { platform }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects are associative, you're trying to put an object inside of an object without a key, try using dissociative arrays, or give the object a key `{"Key:{"platform":platform}}`

```
var that = this, tag_array = "img,object,embed,audio,video,iframe".split(','), 
 video_array = ['EMBED', 'OBJECT', 'VIDEO'], 
 is_ooyala = false, platform = [[ platform ]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the {{ platform }} that you are using a Django Template.

```
var that = this, tag_array = "img,object,embed,audio,video,iframe".split(','),video_array = ['EMBED', 'OBJECT', 'VIDEO'],is_ooyala = false,platform = "{{ platform }}"
```

To use django template variables in javascript you need the quotes

Comment: He never said anything about django.

Comment: Seemed like he's using the template language due to the double curly braces.